# htaccess rule for url with dot

Tags: htaccess, index.php

A development installation has been set up for me that has cloned an existing site. However, the `.htaccess` file no longer works to remove `index.php`.

Could this be because there is a dot in the URL? If so how can I fix it?

So the URL is formatted like this http://www-dev.domian.com/

And the htaccess file like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !www-dev\.domian\.com/$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www-dev\.domian\.com/$1 [L,R=301] 

    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*index\.php [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/system/.* [NC]
    RewriteRule (.*?)index\.php/*(.*) /$1$2 [R=301,NE,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1):

This cannot because the dots in the URL. First need you should check is `mod_rewrite.c` module is enable to your server or not. If yes, You need to alter your `.htaccess`. Try the following last line of your code from

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
```

To

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L, QSA]
```